# SQL sub-query assistance

Tags: sql-server

Use a sub-query that returns the monetary values of all orders that have discounts -- greater than 15% -- List the `orderid` and the order value this last with the highest value at the top.

I keep getting an error message.

```
USE Northwind
GO

SELECT 
    SUM(od.orderid) As OrderID, 
    AS [Order Values]
FROM 
    [Order Details] od
WHERE 
    od.Discount = (SELECT od.Discount
                   FROM [Order Details] od
                   GROUP BY od.discount
                   HAVING od.discount >.15)
GROUP BY 
    od.quantity, od.discount, od.UnitPrice
ORDER BY 
    [Order Values] ASC;
```

Error is:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to tweek it enough to get the results I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lines have problem:
SELECT 
    SUM(od.orderid) As OrderID, 
    AS [Order Values]

There is nothing specified before AS in the 2nd line. Either you have missed a column name before as or you need to remove the "AS OrderID,"
One additional point: Change the = operator of WHERE clause to IN. Tis is to avoid error if your subquery returns multiple values.

Your query will look like this:
USE Northwind
GO

SELECT 
    SUM(od.orderid) AS [Order Values]
FROM 
    [Order Details] od
WHERE 
    od.Discount IN (SELECT od.Discount
                   FROM [Order Details] od
                   GROUP BY od.discount
                   HAVING od.discount >.15)
GROUP BY 
    od.quantity, od.discount, od.UnitPrice
ORDER BY 
    [Order Values] ASC;

Comment: Please start formatting your posts. Also, I highly recommend your offering queries that use JOINs instead of INs.

Comment: Thanks to the responses I was able to change a couple of things and get it to work as needed. I have attached the code below.

USE [Northwind]
GO
SELECT od.OrderID, SUM(od.orderid) AS [Order Values]
FROM [Order Details] od 
WHERE od.Discount IN (SELECT od.Discount 
FROM [Order Details] od 
GROUP BY od.discount 
HAVING od.discount >.15) 
GROUP BY od.orderID, od.quantity, od.discount, od.UnitPrice 
ORDER BY [Order Values] DESC
GO

Thanks to all for there guidance and direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query:

```
SELECT SUM(od.orderid) As OrderID, 
AS [Order Values]
FROM [Order Details] od
WHERE od.Discount = (SELECT od.Discount
                     FROM [Order Details] od
                     GROUP BY od.discount
                     HAVING od.discount >.15
                    )
GROUP BY od.quantity, od.discount, od.UnitPrice
ORDER BY [Order Values] ASC;
```

It has at least two syntactic errors.  The `AS [Order Values]` is just lingering out there.  Incorrectly.  Plus, you have `=` to a subquery that is likely to return multiple rows.  Even after you fix these problems, the query is not going to do what you want, I don't think.

EDIT:

THe query that you want might be:

```
SELECT od.orderid, sum( od.quantity * od.UnitPrice * (1 - od.discount)) as value
FROM [Order Details] od
GROUP BY od.orderid
HAVING sum(case when od.discount > 0.15 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
ORDER BY value desc;
```

Comment: The `having` inside the sub-select is not really necessary either as no aggregation is used.

Comment: He at least wants a sum, perhaps of entire orders having any line items with a discount. The subquery would select non-discounted line items in orders that have at least one discounted item.

Comment: @ErikE . . . Good interpretation.  I didn't realize how far off the original query was (`sum(orderid)` !?!).

Comment: I said it wrong but your query proves you knew what I *meant* to say!